# Submit entity collection with other route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding

I have a strongly typed view

```
@model IEnumerable<MagazineIndex>
```

that represents user input array of objects.Also I have a dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownName",
                   (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["magazines"],
                   new { id = "DropDownName" })
```

When I submit form I get this error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'DropDownName'.

My controller is like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateContent(IList<MagazineIndex> indexes,
                                  string DropDownName)
```

How must I correct bind values?

Comment: Can you please show the line where the exception occurs?

Comment: Do you want to get ALL the items from your dropdown or only the selected one?

Comment: @Linus Caldwell It occurs when I press submit button

Comment: @Alex Ovechkin Only one

Comment: An exception is thrown on a line of code. Please show us the line. If you don't use a debugger, the exception output shows you the code.

Comment: Sorry,this is fully my mistake.I forgot to populate ViewData from HTTPPost action.So sily.Should I delete my question or it can be helpfull? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your HttpPost action you are populating the `ViewData["magazines"]` the same way you did in your Get action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateContent(IList<MagazineIndex> indexes, string DropDownName)
{
    ...
    ViewData["magazines"] = ... same stuff as in your GET action
    return View(indexes);
}
```

This is only necessary to be done if you intend to redisplay the same view in your POST action. If you redirect, you don't need it. The reason you need it is more than obvious. Your view needs to render a DropDown control which depends on its value.